Next.js 14 - Manifest.webmanifest gives 401 unauthorized error on production
Deploying Next.js 14.1.1 with Vercel gives 401 unauthorized error for manifest on production.
It works on Local
manifest.ts:
import {MetadataRoute} from "next";

export default function manifest(): MetadataRoute.Manifest {
  return {
    name: "APP NAME",
    short_name: "APP NAME",
    description:
      "APP_DESCRIPTION",
    theme_color: "#2563eb",
    background_color: "#ffffff",
    display: "standalone",
    orientation: "any",
    scope: "/",
    start_url: "/",
    icons: [
      {
        src: "/favicon.ico",
        sizes: "16x16",
        type: "image/x-icon",
      },
    ],
  };
}

I tried static manifest as well as dynamic manifest, in both cases it gives the same error.
Was expecting it to work the same as dev environment.
